# ADB couldnt detect oneplus2

Tags: adb

I am trying to connect andriod debug shell to oneplus 2, i have enabled USB debugging on my mobile and installed google usb drivers via sdk manager but still adb couldnt detect the mobile

i tried restarting adb server also still facing same issue. I even tried updating the driver via device manager but not luck it says MTP driver is already installed.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: Did u restarted after installing the drivers?

Comment: Yeah i tried restarting

Answer (score 0):

Install PDAnet.
I know its a long shot but it helps to connect phone quicker

http://pdanet.co/a/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Windows**, try **uninstalling the driver** first in case you installed the OnePlus drivers.

Do a full reboot and then try the **latest version** of platform tools, you can download them [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip).

If you are using a **Linux** distribution or **macOS**, make sure you have the lastest platform tools as well: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Restarting the ADB server works in the following way:

```
sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server
```

It's also worth mentioning that some USB ports or hubs might be the culprit here.